# Find the pairs that appear the most times in StoreID and each STOREID has only this pair SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation, self-join

I want to find the pairs of `MOVIEID` that appear more times in the `STOREID`.

Additionally,  each `STOREID` should have only this pair as `MOVIEID`s. My table has 2 columns: `STOREID` and `MOVIEID`.

For example:

```
STOREID | MOVIEID
--------|---------
1       | a
1       | b
1       | c
2       | a
2       | b   
3       | a   
3       | b   
5       | a   
5       | b
```

In this case the answer would be pair: (a,b) 3 times.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What result do you expect if you also add the row (3,c) to your table?

Comment: (a,b) 2 times. only STOREID 2 and 5 have now a pair.

Comment: @Apple12 But wouldn't (a,b,c) have two pairs too at this moment? `(a,b,c) - (1, 3)`; `(a,b) - (2, 5)`? How would you choose then? Also, what RDBMS?

Comment: By pair i meant only 2 items of MOVIEIDs.
So each STOREID has only two (pair) MOVIEIDs. In your case STOREID 1 and 3 have 3 MOVIEIDs.
Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to consider only stores that sell movie pairs. This makes it a lot simpler. First you group by stores and take only those results with two movies. Now to generate pairs of those would be tricky if there were more than two movies. You would need windowing functions. However, for two you get both movies with aggregation functions. One with `min` and the other with `max`. Further those functions ensure, the same pair always has the same order. For example the pair `(a,b)` will always be `(a,b)` and never `(b,a)`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MOVIE_1, MOVIE_2

FROM (
  SELECT MIN(MOVIEID) MOVIE_1
        ,MAX(MOVIEID) MOVIE_2
        ,STOREID
  FROM STORE_MOVIES -- your table
  GROUP BY STOREID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) MOVIE_PAIRS

GROUP BY MOVIE_1, MOVIE_2
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

For `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` I assume `MOVIEID` together with `STOREID` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Although the request does not really make sense, that's not our design/implementation to concern.  I have done with a 3-part self-join to your movies table.  The first (m1) joins to second (m2) on the same store, but for second movie being greater than (m1) movie.  This will prevent conditions of comparing (a,b) vs (b,a).  Then, I am joining (m2) to (m3) by same store, but movie 3 greater than 2.  This is an intentional LEFT-JOIN as not all stores will have more than 2.  In this case, the value at (m3) will be NULL (non-existent).  So, I am looking for where m3.storeID IS NULL.  The JOIN between (m1) and (m2) requires the first and second to exist.  Finally, tacking on the HAVING will show only those pairs that appear at multiple stores.

```
select
      m1.movieID as Movie1,
      m2.movieID as Movie2,
      count(*) TimesPaired
   from
      Movies m1
         JOIN movies m2
            on m1.storeId = m2.storeId
           AND m1.movieId < m2.movieId
           LEFT JOIN movies m3
              on m2.storeId = m3.storeId
             AND m2.movieId < m3.movieId
   where
      m3.storeId IS NULL
   group by
      m1.movieID,
      m2.movieID
   having
      count(*) > 1
```